# a function compares double values in java to get the maximum

Tags: java, netbeans, vector, compare, double

Am making a function that allows me to return a Vector which have the best fitness among the entire population knowing that the fitness is a `double` value, my function doesn't always return the right Vector having the greatest fitness's Vector !!

```
  private Vector globalbest(Vector allpop){
       allpop = allPopulation;
       Vector global =null;
       for(int i=0;i<allPopulation.size()-1;i++)
  {
    double m1 =(fitness((Vector) allpop.get(i+1)));
    double m2 =(fitness((Vector) allpop.get(i)));
    int i1 = Double.compare(m1,m2); // if i1 is positive then the first is greater 
      if( i1 > 0 ){
          global = null;
          global = (Vector) allpop.get(i+1); 
                  }

  }
   return global;
                                           }
```

Wish you could find the mistake ! 
Cause it really made me ill at ease and Thanx

Comment: If you want to see if the first is greater, why don't you just do `if(m1 > m2){ ... }`? Also, you are forgetting to consider the possibility that `m2` might be greater than `m1` (Or if they are equal)

Comment: You are reassigning the input argument immediately, is that on purpose? The input will have no effect on the method's output.

Comment: @Josh M, am looking for the Vector having the greatest fitness value among the `Vector allPopulation` (which is containing hundreds of Vectors)

Comment: @rocketboy, yes you have right but it doesn't affect in the algorithm idea and result, isn't ?

Comment: @GhassenBellagha Yes I understand that, but you are only considering one (`m1 > m2`) of the 3 possibilities... (`m1 > m2`, `m2 > m1`, `m1 == m2`)

Comment: @Josh M, yes i know, and that's normal because am only look after the greatest fitness not the minimum or another having equal to m1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only ever comparing two adjacent vectors in `allpop` as done by this code

```
double m1 =(fitness((Vector) allpop.get(i+1)));
double m2 =(fitness((Vector) allpop.get(i)));
```

This is only relevant for the first two vectors (i.e the first Iteration), after that you should be comparing the next vector to the best of those first two vectors

Try this

```
private Vector globalbest(Vector allpop){
   allpop = allPopulation;
   Vector global =null;
   double m1 =(fitness((Vector) allpop.get(1)));
   double m2 =(fitness((Vector) allpop.get(0)));
   int i1 = Double.compare(m1,m2); // if i1 is positive then the first is greater 
   if( i1 > 0 )
      global = (Vector) allpop.get(1); 
   else
      global = (Vector) allpop.get(0); 
   for(int i = 1;i<allPopulation.size()-1;i++)
   {
       m1 = (fitness((Vector) allpop.get(i)));
       double globalfitness = (fitness((Vector) global));
       int i1 = Double.compare(m1,globalfitness); //
       if( i1 > 0 )
           global = (Vector) allpop.get(i);  
   }
   return global;
}
```

**Edit** As per my comment, you should include type definitions for the Vectors in the method like so

```
 private Vector<Double> globalbest(Vector<Vector<Double>> allpop){...
```

This is assuming your `Vector` allPopulation is a Vector of Doubles, If not then change the `Double` to the type.

Comment: now, when i try `allpop(globalbest(allpop))`  it doesn't give me the Vector with the greatest fitness .. :/ i guess it have a problem with the `hashcode()` it can't find a similar Vector to it .. ?

Comment: You need to put type definitions in your method (see edit) because the method `globalbest` is only returning a single `Vector` while it expects a Vector of vectors. This `allpop(globalbest(allpop))` does not make sense. You should really raise that as a new question as the original was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate to get the maximum value.

```
Vector v = new Vector();
for(int i=0;i<allPopulation.size();i++)
  {
    double m1 =(fitness((Vector) allpop.get(i)));         
    v.add(m1);    
  }

Double max= (Double)Collections.max(v);
Vector global = (Vector) allpop.get(v.indexOf(max));
```

Comment: a good alternate but if i want to clone the `(Vector) allpop.get(i)` having the max `fitness` in a new `Vector` ? any idea ?

Comment: You can achieve this by using: Double max= (Double)Collections.max(v);
       Vector maxFitness= (Vector) allpop.get(v.indexOf(max));